# What would be a good antithesis to "the calm before the storm"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I am trying to make up a idiom in my novel which would be the opposite of "the calm before the storm". I want to express something which happens after the storm but am not able to find any good suggestions. Google is simply presenting me with "the calm after the storm". Can anyone provide any good suggestions ?

Comment: After a storm, especially a metaphorical one (and not including storms at sea), there's usually a wasteland. The aftermath.

Comment: "Calm *after* the storm?"

Comment: What sentiment do you want to convey? Destruction? Relief? Assessment?

Comment: “The morning after the day before”

Comment: Or simply “the morning after...”

Comment: What is the thing that's happening after your storm?

Comment: @MikeGraham: It is more along the lines of an impartial observation. A closer tone to what I am saying would be what user K has suggested "the morning after"

Comment: "The eye of the hurricane"

Comment: I suppose you are looking to discover an antithetical pair here like, “look before you leap” vs “he who hesitates is lost”.  But I don’t think one exists for “calm before the storm”. We are left struggling to invent one like, “the eerie stillness in the wake of battle”.

Comment: **Afterglow**. The storm is personified as  Zeus (the thunder and lightning) having sex with Leto, mother of the god Apollo and the goddess Artemis.

Answer (score 0):

To write the opposite of something, first we need to know the meaning of the word itself.

"***Calm before the storm***" means '***calm in front of trouble***'

The opposite of Calm: Panic(-king) trouble: peace

So: "***Panicking in front of clear skies***" would mean '***panicking in front of peace***'